# How can I account for period (AM/PM) using strftime?

Tags: python, datetime, strptime

Specifically I have code that simplifies to this:

```
from datetime import datetime
date_string = '2009-11-29 03:17 PM'
format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M %p'
my_date = datetime.strptime(date_string, format)

# This prints '2009-11-29 03:17 AM'
print my_date.strftime(format)
```

What gives? Does Python just ignore the period specifier when parsing dates or am I doing something stupid?

Answer (score 312, accepted):

The Python [`time.strftime` docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strftime) say:

> When used with the strptime() function, the **`%p`** directive only
>   affects the output hour field if the **`%I`** directive is used to parse
>   the hour.

Sure enough, changing your `%H` to `%I` makes it work.

Comment: Which is great *unless* your time strings have 0.00pm, (`%I` starts at 1) !!

Comment: @AndyHayden it is 12 PM or 12 AM. Not sure if 0 AM or 0 PM make sense. Only in 24-hour format 0th hour makes sense, but then it is not AM/PM.

Comment: Also note to have your locale in check. If you are using a locale which doesn't use a.m./p.m. you will have to switch to a locale that does use a.m./p.m. I used %I and %p and %p was left blank when using de_DE as locale. Switching to en_GB made %p visible.

Answer (score 93):

```
format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M %p'
```

The format is using `%H` instead of `%I`.  Since `%H` is the "24-hour" format, it's likely just discarding the `%p` information.  It works just fine if you change the `%H` to `%I`.

Answer (score 36):

You used `%H` (24 hour format) instead of `%I` (12 hour format).

Answer (score 24):

Try replacing `%I` with `%H`.

```
from datetime import datetime
print(datetime.today().strftime("%H:%M %p")) # 15:31 AM
```

Becomes

```
from datetime import datetime
print(datetime.today().strftime("%I:%M %p")) # 03:31 AM
```

Answer (score 19):

Try replacing %H (Hour on a 24-hour clock) with %I (Hour on a 12-hour clock)  ?