# Python datetime Period Ignored by strptime?

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime, python-datetime

I'm attempting to strip a `datetime` object from a string, but for some reason the period (AM/PM) is being ignored. Below is some sample code to demonstrate the problem:

```
from datetime import datetime

timeFormat = '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M%p'
amString = "07/26/1994 2:00AM"
pmString = "07/26/1994 2:00PM"

amDate = datetime.strptime(amString, timeFormat)
pmDate = datetime.strptime(pmString, timeFormat)
```

Which is great -- but if I print each date to reveal the value:

```
>>> pmDate
datetime.datetime(1994, 7, 26, 2, 0)
>>> amDate
datetime.datetime(1994, 7, 26, 2, 0)
>>> amDate == pmDate
True
```

I assumed the `amDate` and `pmDate` variables should *not* be equal. Is this common behavior for Python 2.7's `datetime` module or am I missing something obvious? If it is true that periods are useless to `datetime.strptime`, why?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1759485/1832058

Comment: Ermageerd. Thanks guys. Can't believe I didn't see those before. Definitely a duplicate.