# Get AM or PM using 'time'

Tags: python, python-3.x, time

I am trying to get `AM` or `PM` at the last of time I get using `time.ctime()` but I can't find any possible solution. Here is an example:

```
>>> import time
>>> time.ctime()
'Thu Sep 13 8:35:24 2018'
```

It is giving me `Thu Sep 13 8:35:24 2018` but I want the output to be like:
`Thu Sep 13 8:35:24 AM 2018`

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Hello, is this the same you are searching for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759455/how-can-i-account-for-period-am-pm-with-datetime-strptime

Comment: http://strftime.org/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I read the documentation carefully and finally build that piece of code by myself:

```
time.strftime("%a %b %d %I:%M:%S %p %Y")
```