# Pandas - how to convert "hh:mm:ss PM" string to 24-hour timestamp

Tags: python, pandas

Please can someone help me with the correct way to convert "hh:mm:ss AM/PM" Object column to Timestamp.
E.g. **Input = "06:12:39 PM"**
     **Expected Output = 18:12:39**

I tried the below already:

```
df['col'] = pd.to_datetime(df.col,format='%H:%M:%S %p').dt.time
```

However I am getting output = *06:12:39* *with the datatype unchanged*

Not sure where I am going wrong here.
Thank you.

Comment: does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759455/how-can-i-account-for-period-am-pm-using-strftime?

Comment: I don't think that the related question (on strftime and AM/PM) answers the pandas-related question here. The answer depends on what the datatype of the pandas column is. Please update the question with the output of `df['col'].dtype`.

Comment: @Han-KwangNienhuys : My requirement is to have the column datatype changed to DateTime in the mentioned format. XXavier provided me with an almost solution where I can now see the required output minus the Datatype modification - but that much is enough for me to proceed. Thank you all for your help.

Comment: @Pygirl : Yes, it helped actually. I figured out where I was going wrong. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try this

For single datetime value,
`tme='06:12:39 PM'`
`pd.to_datetime(tme).strftime('%H:%M:%S')`
For the column you can do this. This will give you the time in string that you need to convert.
`pd.to_datetime(df['col']).dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')`

Comment: Yes - this worked pretty well - Thank you. Now I have the Time in string and can easily convert this to the required timestamp datatype.