# What is error in my usage of datetime module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

```
sunrise = tt.strftime('%I:%M %p', tt.gmtime(json_data['sys']['sunrise'] - 21600))
sunset = tt.strftime('%H:%M %p', tt.gmtime(json_data['sys']['sunset'] - 21600))
```

Results:

```
Sunrise is: 05:45 PM
Sunset is: 07:20 AM
```

But sunrise is am  and sunset is pm.
Please tell me what's the error.

Answer (score 1):

Possible duplicate of [How can I account for period (AM/PM) using strftime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759455/how-can-i-account-for-period-am-pm-using-strftime).

As stated in the answers to that question, when using the directive `%p`, you should use the 12-hour format `%I` instead of the 24-hour format `%H` to output the equivalent AM or PM for your locale.

You can also try reading the [docs for strftime() here,](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/time.html#time.strftime)

Comment: "Read The Fine Documentation" is always good advice: `;¬)`