# How do I add AM/PM to adatetime.strftime module?

Tags: python, datetime

I've incorporated a datetime module that gives the output of the current time, but it does not include AM/PM in the output. Specifically I am using the "Now" and "strftime" features to give the exact time in the output.  I am wondering what else I might need to add in order for Am or PM to show but I could not find anything to figure it out.  Any help is appreciated.

```
import datetime
my_datetime = datetime.datetime.now()
print("Checkout at:", my_datetime.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
```

For reference, the output right now looks like this:
"Checkout at: 2022-07-28 01:12:07"

Comment: `%p` is the `AM/PM` indicator.

Comment: `%H` is the hour in 24-hour time, you don't need AM/PM.

Comment: How could you not find anything? It's in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes). Just search for PM

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I account for period (AM/PM) using strftime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759455/how-can-i-account-for-period-am-pm-using-strftime)

Comment: Thank you this link was helpful

Comment: thank you @Barmer that advice for %p was helpful